# I need to display a modal window automatically when some condition is true in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

HTML:

```
<div class="modal fade " id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-vertical-centered">
    <div class="modal-content col-lg-pull-3 col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-xs-12 col-sm-12">

      <div class="modal-body" id="modaltext">
          Hello!!!!!!!!!
       </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
if(a==81)
{
$("#myModal").css("display" , "block");  

}
```

modal window should display automatically when the condtion is true. it should not display when the button/div is clikced

Comment: what is the problem or error you are facing?

Comment: what is a???? and your error????

Comment: How you getting the value of 'a' variable?

Comment: I am creating tic tac toe game , in that a is a variable in which i am storing click count. if a == 81 means that you r clicking last box in the board. Thank you peoples for your response ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I mostly do it this way, i send ajax call and on success i do something like this:

Add an anchor tag and pass ahref the modal div id like `#myModal` in your case hide it like this:

```
<a id="modalTrigger" href="#myModal" style="display:none;">dummy</a>
```

put your condition and click anchor tag programmatically:

```
if(a==81)
{
$("#modalTrigger").click();  

}
```

Answer (score 0):

try something like this

```
if(some_condition){
    $('#myModal').modal('show');
}
```